# Angular local storage to avoid data loss on webpage refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-local-storage

I am quite new to Angular. I have a webpage that is presenting information from an array by clicking buttons, entering inputs, etc. I need that when a refresh occurs, the work done on the web page will not be erased. I looked up and found I should use local storage. From an answer to a different question I found that I should use:

```
Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, obj) {
    return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
}
Storage.prototype.getObj = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key))
}
```

to set and get the information.

I still have two questions:

1. I only need it to be saved upon refresh, is there a way to handle this immediately before the refresh? Or should I continuously update the local storage through each change in my properties and variables?
2. When should I get the data? does it make sense to put the get function in my constructor?

Comment: 1. You can use promise for saving data into localstogare and when promise will resolve then you will do the refresh.
2. The moment you need data. You can also use a Loader so that loading will continue till you get the data from localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to you questions

1. To simplify auto-saving, just save to localStorage on any change, but with a throttle (eg max once every second).
   There is an event that is called when tab is closed, onbeforeunload, but it won't fire if the tab crashes, and the amount of things javascript can do in this callback is limited.
2. On reload the page, you probably want the data from localStorage to set the initial state, so load the data in one of the constructors

btw, just use localStorage.getItem() annd localStorage.setItem().  You don't need to set prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Although you can, you shouldn't define any methods over a browser api prototype.
2. Since `localStorage` is asynchronous, you must tell angular that this assyncronous changes are happening, otherwise the ChangeDetector won't work as intended.

I use in my projects this service that I created to solve this issues:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  private localStorage: Storage = localStorage;

  constructor(
    private _zone: NgZone
  ) {
  }

  /**
   * Set given key on browser localStorage
   * @param key
   * @param data
   * @returns {Observable<any>}
   */
  public set(key, data): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
      this._zone.run(() => {
        observer.next(true);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get given key from browser localStorage
   * @param key
   * @returns {Observable<any>}
   */
  public get(key): Observable<any> {
    return this._zone.run(() => {
      return new Observable((observer) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(
            JSON.parse(this.localStorage.getItem(key))
          );
          observer.complete();
        }, 0);
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Remove given key from browser localStorage
   * @param key
   * @returns {Observable<any>}
   */
  public remove(key): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.localStorage.removeItem(key);
      this._zone.run(() => {
        observer.next();
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Just add it to your module providers, inject to your controller/service that needs it and use.